# sorting cards with wildcards

Tags: algorithm, sorting

i am programming a card game and i need to sort a stack of cards by their rank. so that they form a gapless sequence.
in this special game the card with value 2 could be used as a wild card, so for example the cards

```
 2 3 5
```

should be sorted like this

```
 3 2 5
```

because the 2 replaces the 4, otherwise it would not be a valid sequence.

however the cards

```
2 3 4
```

should stay like they are.

restriction: there an be only one '2' used as a wildcard.

```
2 2 3 4
```

would also stay like it is, because the first 2 would replace the ACE (or 1, whatever you call it).

the following would not be a valid input sequence, since one of the 2s must be use as a wildcard and one not. it is not possible to make up a gapless sequence then.

```
2 4 2 6
```

now i have a difficulty to figure out if a 2 is used as a wildcard or not. once i got that, i think i can do the rest of the sorting

thanks for any algorithmic help on this problem!

Comment: If you have the cards `2,2,4,6`, should the resulting sequence be `2,4,2,6` or `4,2,6,2`?

Comment: good question! there can be only one '2' used as wild card. so this case is not a valid sequence in the first place. i will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Change the first `2` you encounter to a `0` (or some other character that isn't used), and use that as the wildcard. Then convert it back to a `2` before displaying.

Comment: So what _would_ be the answer to @Jim's question? `Invalid data`? `6, 2`? `4, 2, 6`? Is it safe to assume that your program will never receive invalid data? Are there any other givens about the input data that we can use?

Comment: @LordTorgamus: as i've said, that is not a valid input sequence, since one of the 2s is not a wildcard and doesn't fit into the sequence then.

Comment: @clamp, you didn't answer my question. Can you assume that you'll never get invalid data? Do you have to check for invalid input? What else, if anything, can we assume about the program state?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: yes, you are guaranteed to get valid input data only! every set of numbers you get will be solvable as a sequence with at most one 2 being a wildcard for any other number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT in response to your clarification to your new requirement:
You're implying that you'll never get data for which a gapless sequence cannot be formed. (If only I could have such guarantees in the real world.) So:

- Do you have a 2?

  - No: your sequence must already be gapless.
  - Yes: You need to figure out where to put it.
- Sort your input. Do you see a gap? Since you can only use one 2 as a wildcard, there can be at most one gap.

  - No: treat the 2 as a legitimate number two.
  - Yes: move the 2 to the gap to fill it in.

<del>EDIT in response to your new requirement:

In this case, just look for the highest single gap, and plug it with a 2 if you have a 2 available.</del>

<del>Original answer:

Since your sequence must be gapless, you could count the number of 2s you have and the sizes of all the gaps that are present. Then just fill in the highest gap for which you have a sufficient number of 2s.</del>

Comment: thanks that leads me on the right way. i didnt mention that, but you cant go lower than 1 so in case of two 2s also make sure to move the wild 2 to the end, if there is a 1 (Ace) present. example: 1 2 3 2